# Ordinary Chain Rule Confusion

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ be the function defined in Q1, and let $g$ be a function such that $g^\prime(x)=\sin(\sin(x+1))$ and $g(0)=2$. Find $(f\circ g)^\prime(0)$ and $(g\circ f)^\prime(0)$.
>
> For $x\neq0$, the rules of differentiation give $f^\prime(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$, so by the chain rule, we have $$(f\circ g)^\prime(0)=f^\prime(g(0))g^\prime(0)=f^\prime(2)g^\prime(0)=\left[4\sin\dfrac12-\cos\dfrac12\right]\sin(\sin(1)).$$ And $(g\circ f)^\prime(0)=g^\prime(f(0))f^\prime(0)=0$ (since $f^\prime(0)=0$, as proved above).

I understand that the chain rule states that $[f(g(x))]'=g'(x)f'(g(x))$.
However in this example the solution differentiates with respect to $x$ and the evaluates at $g(0)$. I don't understand why you can do this.  The formula implies I have to differentiate $f$ with respect to $g(x)$.

Comment: No, the formula implies you differentiate $f$, then you evaluate it at $x=g(x)$.

Comment: Sort of get it now but isn't this the same thing as differentiating wrt $g(x)$?

Comment: its a similar thing to differentiating $f \circ g$ wrt g

Comment: @lemony9201 No, consider $f(x)=(x+1)^2$, if you differentiate it with respect to $x+1$ you'll get $x+1$. But if you differentiate that same function with respect to $x$ then you evaluate it at $x+1$ you'll get $2x+4$.

Comment: If you differentiate it wrt $(x+1)$ don't you get $2(x+1)$? then times it by $g'(x)=1$ where $g(x)=(x+1)$, you get the correct answer?

Comment: @lemony9201 Nope as you can check for yourself in wolframalpha.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $f$ (with respect to $x$) and take the value of the derivative at $g(x)$. This gives you $$f'(g(x))$$

Evaluate the derivative of $g$ (with respect to $x$) in $x$: this gives $$g'(x)$$

Take the product : $f'(g(x))\,g'(x)$

Take $x=0$: $$f'(g(0))\,g'(0)$$

Reminder: $f$ is a *function*, $f(x)$ is a *real number* (in the present case).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to think about this in terms of differentials that.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du} \dfrac{du}{dx}$

Define a function.

$h(x) = f(g(x)) $

Let $u = g(x)$

$\dfrac{dh}{dx} = \dfrac{dh}{du} * \dfrac{du}{dx} = f'(g(x))\times g'(x) $

You see here that $u = g(x)$ is still a function of x, so when you differentiate you differentiate to a function of $x$. $g(x)$ is a rather function, not an independent variable, so it cant be differentiated to.